# Reading dictionary to file overwrites with only new information

Tags: python

I have read a text file into a dictionary, used functions to add/remove records in the dictionary, and then wrote it back to the text file. The format of the text file is as follows:

```
    First Name
    2018-11-05 10:12:15
    First string
    Second string
    Third string
    
    Second Name
    2014-01-02 14:21:11
    First string
    Second string
    Third string
```

This is part of my code:

```
name = {'First Name':['2018-11-05 10:12:15','First string', 'Second String', 
    'Third String']} and so on

     def addName(names):
        print("Adding to name list")
        while True:
            answer = input("Enter name to add or <ENTER> to exit: ")
            if answer == "":
                print("Exiting Add Names")
                break
            elif answer in name:
                print("Name already exist")
            elif answer not in [name]:
                new_name_info = str(input("Enter name info: "))
                new_name_dict = {answer: [datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), new_plant_info]}
                name.update(new_names_dict)
                print("Add new name info successful.")
                break
    
    def Write_back_into_file(diction):
            print("Writing it back and exiting")
            with open("filename", "w") as file:
                for key in diction.keys():
                    namess = list(name[key])
                    file.write(key + "\n" + "".join(namess) + "\n")
```

However, instead of writing the updated dictionary back to the file, the entire file was overwritten with only the new keys that were added to the dictionary.

I understand how "w" mode works but I intended the updated dictionary, after adding and deleting records, will be written to the file.

So I'm not sure how to write the updated dictionary back to the text file in the original format.

Comment: Appending would add duplicate entries to my file in this case

Comment: There are too many errors in the code you present to work out what it does.The function `addName()` accepts `names` as a parameter, but the code in the function never refers to it and instead tests `answer in name` in line 8, and `answer not in [name]` in line 10. And the definition of `name` itself is not in the code you present. It appears to be a `dict` because you call `name.update()`, but if so, the test `answer not in [name]` will always be `False` because it can only be `True` is if `answer` is a `dict`, but it's the `string` value returned by `input()`, so the update call won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the typos something like that should work:

```
def Write_back_into_file(diction):
    print("Writing it back and exiting")
    with open("filename", "w") as file:
        for key in diction.keys():
            file.write(key + "\n" + "\n".join(diction[key]) + "\n\n")
```

And of course you have to pass your dictionary "name" to the function:

```
Write_back_into_file(name)
```